# Store Products-Database on an Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I want to store the products for a vending machine I'm building on an Arduino that controlls the whole machine. In Python you can do it via dictionary:

ID: [price, name, volume]

```
products = {
    1: [1.09, "Coke", 0.33],
    2: [0.71, "Coke Zero", 0.33],
    3: [0.44, "Water", 0.5],
    4: [1.09, "Sprite", 0.33]
}
```

But I don't know how to do it Arduino / C++.
Anyone help me?

And there's also no `if ID in products`. How can I fix this?

Comment: In C++ you could use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`. Arduino is a sad, pathetic beast when it comes to C++, so I doubt it is supported out of the box.

Comment: You better use at least Raspberry PI for such apps, Arduino is very limited by memory size, CPU power etc. But question itslef is out of scope of SO - you need a textbook.

Comment: @Slava it does'nt help.

Comment: You'll want to store the data either with the executable (if the data is constant) or in some Non-Volatile memory like Flash or MRAM.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I want to store it with the executable because it's constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what Arduino supports and what not, maybe try something like this and see if it works:

```
struct Product
{
    float price;
    char const *name;
    float volume;
};

Product const products[4] =
{
    { 1.09, "Coke", 0.33 },
    { 0.71, "Coke Zero", 0.33 },
    { 0.44, "Water", 0.5 },
    { 1.09, "Sprite", 0.33 }
};
```

And then you could refer to your products as

`products[0].name`, `products[0].price`, `products[0].volume` etc.

Comment: @Killzone Kid Is there any special reason, that you have used `char const *` instead of `std::string` ?

Comment: @JeJo Arfuino is weird, don’t think IDE has `std::string`, that would have been too easy :). There is however an alternative, something called `String`, but it doesn’t look like OP needs a dynamic container.

Comment: @KillzoneKid I am also not familiar with that, so didn't know about it. Wanted to make sure, is it the reason you suggested `const char*`. Thatks for the info BTW.